# How to fetch suggest items from another model in sap.m.input?

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a table in which a column has sap.m.Input. This table has a model but for input field i need suggest items from different model. Following is the code but it is not working fine, Please suggest me some alternate way or help me correct my error.

```
  new sap.m.Input({value:'{CUST_NAME}',
                   showSuggestion:true,  
                   liveChange : function(oEvent) { 
                         console.log(oEvent.getSource().getValue());
                          console.log(this.getValue());                                     
                          if (this.getValue().length > 0) {         
                             var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
                             var serviceUrl = "/serviceurl/?$filter=startswith(Name,%27an%27)";  
                             oModel.loadData(serviceUrl,null, false, "GET",false, false, null);  
                             this.setModel(oModel); 
                             console.log(oModel)
                             this.bindAggregation("suggestionItems", "/d/results", new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "{Name}"}));
                          }
                   }        
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a second [named model](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/91f0d1c56f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070.html). The `setModel(oModel,sModelName)` function takes a second optional to pass the name of the model. So every control can have multiple models as long as they have different names.

To access the named model use the `modelName>` prefix in your bindings (you have to use it for absolute and for relative bindings!).

In your case there is no need to create a new model for the suggestion items every time, too.

```js
  var oSuggestionModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();  
  oSuggestionModel.forceNoCache(true);
  new sap.m.Input({value:'{CUST_NAME}',
                   showSuggestion:true,
                   suggestionItems: { 
                      path: 'suggestion>/d/results', 
                      template: new sap.ui.core.Item({text: "{suggestion>Name}"})
                   },
                   liveChange : function(oEvent) { 
                         console.log(oEvent.getSource().getValue());
                          console.log(this.getValue());
                          //eventually clear the model: oSuggestionModel.setData({});
                          if (this.getValue().length > 0) {         
                             var serviceUrl = "/serviceurl/?$filter=startswith(Name,%27an%27)";  
                             oSuggestionModel.loadData(serviceUrl);  
                          }
                   }        
    }).setModel(oSuggestionModel, "suggestion");
```

Also there is no need to load the data synchronous. After you have set up the binding the data will automatically be displayed when the model is filled later.

Comment: Thanks, Its working fine now. There is one problem that suggestions are coming in upward direction of the input field but i need them downwards. As i am a newbie i am not getting how to do it

Comment: Normally the suggestions appear on top of the input field when there is not enough room below. You can try that [here](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.InputSuggestionsDynamic/preview): rezise window to a very slim height and type *h* for example.

Comment: I am facing a problem now, instead of service calling i am now using a model and filters. So how will i get the binding to perform filtering. I am using oEvent.getSource().getBinding() but its giving undefined. Please help me

Comment: should be `oEvent.getSource().getBinding("suggestionItems").filter(...)`